# Why terminal in windows doesn't run my java class?

Tags: java

I coded a java file in a folder which is on my desktop.I copied windows terminal to this folder to execute and compile this file.When I compiled the file there was no problem.But when I tried to run the file,the same file it did found when I was compiling,it didnt found the file(like what?).

*Screenshots*
[image: Compiling]

[image: Running(Failed)]

**What I've tried so far**

I tried including a class path in my terminal code but it didnt change anything.[image]

Where am I making a mistake please help me solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because, you're not running it from the directory, relative to which, `com/tunayilmaz/software/` directory exists.

Create a directory hierarchy, like `../com/tunayilmaz/software/` and put your `.class` file there. Then run `java software` from the root directory, where your `/com` is located.

[docs.oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html):

> compiled .class files should be in a series of directories that reflect the package name.